# Request to firebase doesn't work, errorCode 400 badRequest

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use Firebase to send notifications.

I have read the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group?authuser=3#managing-device-groups-on-the-app-server,but I got badRequest response.

My request HTTP GET here to get the notification_key:

```
{
  method  : 'GET',
  uri     : https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification?notification_key_name=<notification_keyname>,
  json    : 'true',
  headers : {
    Authorization  : key=<API_KEY>,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    project_id     : senderId,
  },
}
```

What is wrong with this request?

Comment: Try it without the quotes around `'Content-Type'`

Comment: did you try doing it outside of code? E.g. postman? does that work as expecteD?

Comment: @BobSnyder : can't put ' - ' in key in json, so I can't run that without quotes.

Comment: @BojanPetkovic : senderId is relative to the server the request comes from so I got an error 401 "Unauthorized" from postman or Insomnia

Comment: try running it form the server directly.  (possibly with CURL)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  method  : 'GET',
  uri     : https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification?notification_key_name=<notification_keyname>,
  json    : 'true',
  headers : {
    Authorization  : key=<API_KEY>,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    project_id     : senderId,
  },
}
```

I could see two unnecessary commas (`,`):

```
    project_id : senderId,
},
```